# command 'exec master..xp_cmdshell' does not creating file

Tags: sql, sql-server, file, xp-cmdshell

I'm not getting success with this command

```
DECLARE @cmd sysname, @var sysname
SET @var = 'Hello world'
SET @cmd = 'echo ' + @var + ' > C:\var_out.txt'
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Already tried several examples, but it did not work. 
The command runs but the file simply does not create

Comment: Are you looking for the file on your machine or on the SQL box?

Comment: Does the account used for xp_cmdshell (normally the SQL Server Service account) have permission to write there? I would guess not.

Comment: Where do you expect this file could be created? It will be created on the SQL SERVER local drive c:\ not on the client PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What account is your SQL Server running under? Maybe it doesn't have enough privileges. If this is true, you can use sp_xp_cmdshell_proxy_account instead.

However, I believe you are trying to find the file on your machine instead of server. And what you are doing is storing the file to the server. Try to do it on the local SQL Server.

Comment: This is a test and the sql is local

Comment: Are you running it on a virtual machine? Maybe linked server? Can you check output of following TSQL commands: `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'hostname'` and `EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'dir c: \'`

Answer (score -1):

You must enable some settings before execute this script with sp_xp_cmdshell

```
USE [master]
GO

sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE;
GO
```

---

Comment: Uh… what? What settings? Also, see formatting tips.